# QuickBooks integration with ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, quickbooks

Please provide some link or demo code for QuickBooks integration with ASP.NET.
I have App Token, OAuth Consumer Key, OAuth Consumer Secret.

Comment: Can you explain it a bit more pls ?

Comment: The next step would be to head over to the Intuit Developer web site and download the QB SDK. Free registration might be required IIRC

Comment: I want to connect QuickBooks and i have QuickBooks's login credential.I created some app(which having App Token, OAuth Consumer Key, OAuth Consumer Secret.) and want to connect it with my asp.net application.Like creating a new customer, creating  invoice etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the developer documentation here https://developer.intuit.com/app/developer/homepage

First you need to signup as a developer and then have to create an app in the developer's dashboard: https://developer.intuit.com/app/developer/dashboard.
[image]

After creating an app you can get your client id and client secret in the app setting screen. Also you will find the sdk or similar code for your technology stack

[image]

here is a list of API endpoints from where you can fetch and post the data
https://developer.intuit.com/app/developer/qbo/docs/api/accounting/most-commonly-used/account